# Putting labels on a bar chart in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-bar

I am having a little bit of trouble inserting labels on a bar chart in ggplot2.

So far, I have been able to create the bar chart.

```
Pizza_bar <- ggplot(Pizza_Data_Research_Rockstar, aes(Number_of_times_eaten_pizza))
Times_eaten_pizza_7_days_bar <- Pizza_bar + geom_bar()
Times_eaten_pizza_7_days_bar
```

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.

The challenge becomes labeling the count of the different categories. Since I am newbie at R, I went searching for code examples but keep getting error messages.

```
ggplot(Pizza_Data_Research_Rockstar, aes(x= Number_of_times_eaten_pizza, y = count))+ 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") + 
geom_text(aes(label=count), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5) + 
theme_minimal()
```

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous. Don't know how to
>   automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to
>   continuous. Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows =
>   FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of
>   rows: 46, 0

That is the closest that I have gotten to adding labels.

Could someone please help? Thank you.

Luis

Comment: can you post some parts of your data?

Comment: I am willing to do that. however, I don't see an upload button here. could you tell me how I could post the data?

Comment: Ok, so i got the labels to work. However, my y-axis is out of whack.

Comment: Here are my data and code. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You can copy/paste first 5-10 rows of your data.

Comment: part 1  - data  > count(Number_of_times_eaten_pizza)
  Number.of.times.eaten.pizza.in.the.past.7.days freq
1                                              0   13
2                                              1   15
3                                              2    2
4                                              3    9
5                                              4    3
6                                              6    4

Comment: part 2 > RR_Pizza_df <- data.frame(Days=c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "6"), Freq=c("13", "15", "2", "9", "3", "4"))
> head(RR_Pizza_df)
  Days Freq
1    0   13
2    1   15
3    2    2
4    3    9
5    4    3
6    6    4
> r <- ggplot(data = RR_Pizza_df, aes(x=Days, y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
> r

Comment: Number of times eaten pizza in the past 7 days
2
3
0
3
3
1
0
1
3
2
0
4
3

Comment: is that what you meant by copy/paste first 5-10 rows of data?

Comment: Very difficult to understand what you are trying to do... Can't you combine all the data in one dataframe before plotting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really could't understand your data, so I made up my own:

```r
library(ggplot2)

Days = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Friday")
Pizzas = c(40, 50, 10, 25)
Pizzadf = as.data.frame(cbind(Days, Pizzas))
Pizzadf$Pizzas = as.numeric(as.character(Pizzadf$Pizzas))

Pizzadf
#>       Days Pizzas
#> 1   Monday     40
#> 2  Tuesday     50
#> 3 Thursday     10
#> 4   Friday     25

ggplot(data = Pizzadf, aes(x = Days, y = Pizzas))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Pizzas), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Try to modify and adjust.

Comment: that makes it a lot easier.

Comment: How many columns do you have? How many columns are giving information for your plot?

Comment: thank you that worked. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi, the data has 18 columns total. The plot is giving information for one column, number of times eaten pizza. Is this the question that you are asking?